# hash[key] is to hash.fetch(key) as @ivar is to what?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

To expand on the title: How can I access an instance variable (`@ivar`) in a way that results in an exception if the instance variable hasn't been initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built in method that provides this functionality in respect to instance variables, however;

Since `Hash#[]` is analogous to `@ivar` (or `instance_variable_get(:@ivar)`) in your example then `Hash#fetch` would be analogous to

```
def instance_variable_fetch(sym)
  raise(NameError, "instance variable not found: #{sym}") unless instance_variable_defined?(sym) 
  instance_variable_get(sym)
end
```

Example:

```
@var = 42
instance_variable_fetch(:@var)
#=> 42
@ivar = nil
instance_variable_fetch(:@ivar)
#=> nil
instance_variable_fetch(:@other_var)
#=> NameError: instance variable not found: @other_var
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `h[k]` is the easy form of `h.fetch(k)` then by analog:

```
@ivar
instance_variable_get(:@ivar)
```

The [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) method provides arbitrary access to instance variables.

The difference here is that `h[k]` calls `Hash#[]` which returns `nil` if no key is found, while `h.fetch(k)` calls `Hash#fetch` and **raises an exception if the key is not found**. This difference is important enough to note here.

Answer (score 1):

To do that I believe you would need to access the value of the instance variable, from with the class, through a getter exclusively. The getter could be made private.

```
class C
  attr_writer :ivar
  alias :o_instance_variable_get :instance_variable_get

  def ivar
    givar
  end

  def instance_variable_get(v)
    (v==:@ivar || v=="@ivar") ? givar : o_instance_variable_get(v)
  end

  def tell_ivar
    puts "#{givar} is the value of @ivar"
  end

  private

  def givar
    raise RuntimeError, "@ivar has not been set" unless
      instance_variables.include?(:@ivar)
    @ivar
  end
end
```

```
i = C.new
i.instance_variables
  #=> []
i.ivar
  #=> RuntimeError (@ivar has not been set)
i.instance_variable_get(:@ivar)
  #=> RuntimeError (@ivar has not been set)
i.tell_ivar
  #=> RuntimeError (@ivar has not been set)
i.ivar = 'cat'
i.instance_variables
  #=> [:@ivar]
i.ivar
  #=> "cat" 
i.instance_variable_get(:@ivar)
  #=> "cat" 
i.tell_ivar
  # cat is the value of @ivar
```

The (public) getter method `ivar` may be removed if it is not wanted.

`@ivar` will return `nil` regardless of whether it has not been defined or has been initialize to `nil`. Similarly,  [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) returns `nil` if the instance variable has not been defined or `nil` is its current value. `i.instance_variables.include(:@ivar)` is the only way I could think of to determine whether `@ivar` has been defined, possibly equal to `nil`.